# Re-connect to metro server after disconnect

Tags: react-native

I am running `react-native run-android` with physical android device plug in with usb port.

However, when the cable is disconnected. I can't reconnect back to metro server automatically.

I have to rerun `react-native run-android` which was quite a waste of time.

Is there any command that can use to reconnect?

Comment: Are you working on Windows?

Comment: @MinhDao yes I am working on Windows 10 with react native 0.61

Comment: Well, I was facing the same problem. And bad news is: there might be no solution for Windows. I have worked on MacOS, and this is the only way I know to solve your issue.

Answer (score 41):

try in terminal `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` and after that in the Metro Bundler Window hit `r` key

Comment: Excellent, This saves me alot of time.

Answer (score 15):

Check that the device is reconnected to the machine with:

```
adb devices
```

Reroute the connection to the development server with:

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

Answer (score -11):

try to down grade the nodejs to less than v12 and reinstall npm

Comment: please delete this. proven to be misleading